# how to run visual studio or nunit as administrator from teamcity

Tags: nunit, teamcity, watin

I am currently running my tests using teamcity. Gaving the following error

SetUp method failed. System.UnauthorizedAccessException : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-

Any idea how can I set it to run as administrator as I am using windows 7.

Answer (score 4):

I also use TeamCity and WatiN. Here is what I did to make sure TeamCity can run as Administrator, but not as Local System (because it is better to have a real user when you run IE).

- Create a new user (for example "TeamCity")
- Add this user to Administrator group
- Open the service console window (http://media.techtarget.com/rms/misc/admintools7.jpg) and look for the teamcity agent: "Team City Build Agent Service"
- Right click on it, and go to "log on" tab. Enter the newly created user

Hope this helps