# Exception thrown after trying to get access to a network drive

Tags: c#, teamcity, build-process

At the moment I'm setting up a new project on my TeamCity server, which should simply build and execute a C# application.

The application needs access to a network drive for the execution, so the path to the network drive is passed as argument.
The build step works well, but I get a 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' according to the path of the network drive, after executing it.
The TeamCity account has administrative priviliges and everything works well if I start it manually.

So, I assume my user account or the build agent still does not posses administrative priviliges? Do I have to set more specific settings at my TeamCity server?

Sorry if this post is a repetition, but among others, this post [0] does not worked for me.
Any ideas? Thx a lot in advance!

[0] [how to run visual studio or nunit as administrator from teamcity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428070/how-to-run-visual-studio-or-nunit-as-administrator-from-teamcity)

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Are you referencing the network path as a mapped drive or using the UNC path?

Comment: I'm using the UNC path.
I still assume that TeamCity does not posses all necessary permissions...

Comment: UNC is good. When you say you start it manually are you logged in as that same admin user, and do you mean manually from within TeamCity or something else?

Comment: Manually means: I'll execute it directly on the build machine (Windows 7) under the same user account.
The TeamCity service runs under this account too.
Thx in advance :)

Comment: That totally sounds like it should work, particularly since it shoulds like it's a domain account you're using? It could be a setting in the local security policy on the machine for the user account to prevent it from running as a service. It sounds like the issue might be due to it running non-interactively rather than the user itself. Are you trying to run an executable off the network drive or is it just file access?

Comment: Yes, it's a domain account.
Hmmm okay, it seems that the problem is not TeamCity related...
It's just a file access.
So, my conclusion is that the TeamCity service does not have all necessary (administrative) permissions...

Comment: Already solved it: TeamCity service had to be changed to the user account

Answer (score 0):

The solution of my question is the same as in this question:

[Trying to get a Windows Service to run an executable on a shared drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134805/trying-to-get-a-windows-service-to-run-an-executable-on-a-shared-drive)